# Ansible don't configure interfaces in firewalld past reload

Tags: linux, ansible, centos, firewalld

The task is to write a playbook to move interfaces to other zones, but when the firewalld daemon is restarted, the interface returns to the standard zone. Perhaps this is due to the configuration of NetworkManager, but the solutions that I found on the Internet do not satisfy the task. Also, the main difficulty is that when designing a playbook, you cannot use the shell plugin.

If you have any thoughts about solving this problem, write.

Linux Distribution - RedOs (I from Russia :) )

That my playbook:

```
############## NAT CONFIGURATION ##############
---

- name: NAT CONFIGURATION
  hosts: RTR1 
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
```

############## FIREWALLD ######################

```
- name: firewalld installing
  yum:
    name: firewalld
    state: latest

- name: firewalld enable and start
  service:
    name: firewalld
    enabled: true
    state: started

- name: Interfaces
  
  firewalld:
    zone: public
    interface: ens33
    state: disabled
    permanent: true
    immediate: true

  firewalld:
    zone: internal
    interface: ens36
    state: enabled
    permanent: true
    immediate: true
  
  firewalld:
    zone: external
    interface: ens33
    state: enabled
    permanent: true
    immediate: true

- name: protocols Internal

  firewalld:
    zone: internal
    service: "{{ item }}"
    state: enabled
    permanent: true
    immediate: true
  with_items:
    - ssh
    - mysql
    - dns
     

- name: protocols External

  firewalld:
    zone: external
    service: "{{ item }}"
    state: enabled
    permanent: true
    immediate: true
  with_items:
    - ssh
    - mysql
    - http
    - https
    - dns

- name: save and reload
  
  service:
    name: firewalld
    state: reloaded
```

Comment: I broke the structure of the playbook, but I think the meaning is clear

Comment: To start with, your task named `- name: Interfaces` declares several times the module `firewalld:`. You should see in your playbook output a duplicate dict key warning. In that case only the last definition is retained so the first two definitions will never play. You need a tasks item (i.e. a list element starting with a dash `-`) for each module execution.

Comment: For the rest, you might want to have a look at the following links which seem to apply to your case: https://access.redhat.com/discussions/1455033, https://github.com/ansible-collections/ansible.posix/issues/75. As you will see you might be able to workarround the problem by changing the zone on the network card with nmcli and [there is a module for that](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/nmcli_module.html)